# How to listen for both keypress and keydown events in Elm?

Tags: elm

I want to listen to both `keypress` and `keydown` events in Elm. But if I have the following, only the `keydown` events will be listened to:

```
textarea
    [ onWithOptions "keypress" (Options False True) <| Json.Decode.map KeyPress keyCode
    , onWithOptions "keydown" (Options False True) <| Json.Decode.map KeyDown keyCode
    ] []
```

If I change the `Options` to not `preventDefault`, then both events will be listened to. But I need to `preventDefault` in order to not let tab keys from changing focus.

Any way to do this in Elm?

Answer (score 9):

In Elm 19, to access keys pressed, you can use [Browser.Events](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Events) which is a part of the [Elm Browser library](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/). If you want to capture what key is down, you could use something like this:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode

type Key
  = Character Char
  | Control String

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Browser.Events.onKeyDown keyDecoder

keyDecoder : Decode.Decoder Msg
keyDecoder =
    Decode.map toKey (Decode.field "key" Decode.string)


toKey : String -> Msg
toKey string =
    case String.uncons string of
        Just ( char, "" ) ->
            PressedLetter char

        _ ->
            Control string
```

Adapted from [here](https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/1.0.0/notes/keyboard.md).

Answer (score 1):

Pre Elm 0.19, I recommend you to use [elm-lang/keyboard](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/keyboard/1.0.1/Keyboard). This package uses subscriptions and it's very easy to use. You can subscribe to keydown and keyup at the same time.

For your specific case:
The default action for a keydown event is to trigger a keypress event. If you prevent that default behaviour, you will not get the keypress events.

You can read more about keydown events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

Maybe you just need to use keyup and keydown.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: problem with elm-lang/keyboard is that doesn't work for specific input elements, that I'm aware of... seems to apply to the whole webpage only.

Comment: Yes, but in your update function you can handle how those events interact with your model.
I've edited my answer with more information about your case.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the [docs](https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/master/notes/keyboard.md) and [HParker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800798/541208), I wrote up a more complete solution using Elm 0.19 and subscriptions.

It adds a Subscription for `Browser.Events.onKeyUp/Down`, and handles them in a  top-level Msg with a subMsg for easier processing. It includes Alt, Ctrl, Shift, and Meta (Windows Key/Option).

Remember that `onKeyUp/Down` and `onKeyPressed` handle characters differently (where up/down use the appropriate case, where pressed does not).

```
import Browser.Events
import Json.Decode as Decode


type KeyEventMsg
    = KeyEventControl
    | KeyEventAlt
    | KeyEventShift
    | KeyEventMeta
    | KeyEventLetter Char
    | KeyEventUnknown String


type Msg
    = KeyPressedMsg KeyEventMsg
    | KeyReleasedMsg KeyEventMsg


update : Msg -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg =
    case msg of
        KeyPressedMsg keyEventMsg ->
            case keyEventMsg of
                KeyEventShift ->
                    ( { model | shiftIsPressed = True }, Cmd.none )

                _ ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )

        KeyReleasedMsg keyEventMsg ->
            case keyEventMsg of
                KeyEventShift ->
                    ( { model | shiftIsPressed = False }, Cmd.none )

                _ ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ Browser.Events.onKeyDown keyPressedDecoder
        , Browser.Events.onKeyUp keyReleasedDecoder
        ]


keyPressedDecoder : Decode.Decoder Msg
keyPressedDecoder =
    Decode.map (toKeyEventMsg >> KeyPressedMsg) (Decode.field "key" Decode.string)


keyReleasedDecoder : Decode.Decoder Msg
keyReleasedDecoder =
    Decode.map (toKeyEventMsg >> KeyReleasedMsg) (Decode.field "key" Decode.string)


toKeyEventMsg : String -> KeyEventMsg
toKeyEventMsg eventKeyString =
    case eventKeyString of
        "Control" ->
            KeyEventControl

        "Shift" ->
            KeyEventShift

        "Alt" ->
            KeyEventAlt

        "Meta" ->
            KeyEventMeta

        string_ ->
            case String.uncons string_ of
                Just ( char, "" ) ->
                    KeyEventLetter char

                _ ->
                    KeyEventUnknown eventKeyString
```